# Python + Selenium: how to automatically add test name and ids parameter or number to screenshot name?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, screenshot, naming

I am learning how to write tests in Python + Selenium based on Page Object.

In general, the test code itself looks like this:

```
pytest.mark.parametrize("first_name", [double_first_name, empty_form, long_first_name],
                     ids=["double_first_name", "empty_form", "long_first_name"])
def test_reg_form_name(browser, first_name):
    passport_reg_page = RegForm(browser)
    passport_reg_page.go_to_site()
    passport_reg_page.reg_page()
    passport_reg_page.reg_first_name(first_name)
    passport_reg_page.reg_button()
    passport_reg_page = RegFormExpectations(browser)
    passport_reg_page.reg_expect_name()
    assert rt_passport_reg_page.reg_expect_name()
    browser.save_screenshot('screenshots/test_reg_1.png')
```

How to write and call a function so that the name of the test + parameter ids is automatically added to the name of the screenshot, or at least the name of the test + the number of each parameter run? For example:

```
browser.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{"test_reg_form_name"}+"_"+{"ids"}.png')
```

or

```
browser.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{"test_reg_form_name"}+"_"+{"001,002,003..."}.png')
```

I've been proposed to try:

```
def test_name(self, request):
    testname = request.node.name
    return testname
```

but got notice "Method 'test_name' may be 'static'"

Also the next method helps to get def name but I see no sense to write its name for further getting it:

```
browser.save_screenshot(f'screenshots/{test_reg_page.__name__}_1.png')
```

Comment: you are passing `first_name` as a parameter, so you can append it. so it can be like `f "screenshots/test_reg_form_name/{first_name}.png"` and if you might need to run these cases multiple days/times, you can add time in the folder name(`screenshots/01131301`) or on file name(`screenshots/test_reg_form_name/{first_name}_01131301.png"`

Comment: Thank U so much! Partly I've solved this issue. Screenshot takes parameter into its name but `parameter = var` and I'd like screenshot to take also `ids` from `pytest.mark.parametrize`